# SBCL statistical profiler warns of undefined function

Tags: profiling, common-lisp, sbcl

SBCL 1.3.9 produces the following error when I attempt to run the statistical profiler. Is `start-profiling` not exported?

```
* (in-package :cl-user)
* (require :sb-sprof)
* (sb-sprof:with-profiling (:report :flat) (bnb::solve))
; in: SB-SPROF:WITH-PROFILING (:REPORT :FLAT)
;     (SB-SPROF:START-PROFILING :MAX-DEPTH 4611686018427387903 :THREADS
;      (LIST SB-THREAD:*CURRENT-THREAD*))
;
; caught STYLE-WARNING:
;   undefined function: SB-SPROF:START-PROFILING
;
; compilation unit finished
;   Undefined function:
;     SB-SPROF:START-PROFILING
;   caught 1 STYLE-WARNING condition

debugger invoked on a UNDEFINED-FUNCTION in thread
#<THREAD "main thread" RUNNING {100292C913}>:
  The function SB-SPROF:START-PROFILING is undefined.

Type HELP for debugger help, or (SB-EXT:EXIT) to exit from SBCL.

restarts (invokable by number or by possibly-abbreviated name):
  0: [ABORT] Exit debugger, returning to top level.
```

Comment: I know I am very late to the party but I'd like to add something in case someone else stumbles upon this question.

The `sb-sprof` package is not properly supported on windows. `sb-sprof:start-profiling` uses an alien function defined in `/runtime/interrupt.c` called `install_handlers`, which uses the low level function `ll_install_handlers`. This function is very specific to unix like systems, which is why it isn't supported on windows. Removing the `#-win32` directives won't help, as the runtime code is wrapped in `#IFNDEF LISP_FEATURE_WIN32` too.

Answer (score 1):

It seems a problem with your distribution. please update to the last SBCL wich is

[The most recent version is SBCL 1.3.18, released May 30, 2017](https://github.com/sbcl/sbcl/blob/0186788aec9c68ee47a4de40ae1d190495be050d/contrib/sb-sprof/sb-sprof.lisp)

But if you take a look at the sources in github

```
git log -S start-profiling --source --all

commit 63f714af62d0ccdb9d4a793ab0245b036c3d8531 refs/tags/sbcl_1_0
Author: Juho Snellman <jsnell@iki.fi>
Date:   Fri Nov 17 02:15:47 2006 +0000

    0.9.18.58:
            Further SB-SPROF improvements.

            * Allocation profiling on gencgc. When the profiler is running in
              allocation profiling mode, the gc will signal profiler ticks
              when new allocation regions are opened.
            * Add :LOOP keyword argument to WITH-PROFILING, to allow specifying
              whether the body should be evaluated repeatedly until the maximum
              sample count is reached.
            * Improve merging of code-components with multiple debug-funs,
              better handling of multiple functions with the same name
            * More documentation
            * Also update the stepper documentation

commit 554397512eea9d6e30067c5edc2def42006a5327 refs/tags/sbcl_0_8_12
Author: Christophe Rhodes <csr21@cam.ac.uk>
Date:   Mon Jun 21 11:33:35 2004 +0000

    0.8.11.20:
            Add SB-SPROF contrib
```

That funcion was added a lot time ago, so please try the latest code and follow [the manual](http://www.sbcl.org/manual/#Statistical-Profiler)

also if you inspect the code it [has this mark](https://github.com/sbcl/sbcl/blob/0186788aec9c68ee47a4de40ae1d190495be050d/contrib/sb-sprof/sb-sprof.lisp)

```
#-win32
```

So if you are using windows 32 bits this should not work

Comment: Thanks anquegi for pointing out `#-win32`. I've updated to the newest SBCL (for Windows-64) as you suggest, and notice that both :WIN32 and :X86-64 are in *FEATURES*. I removed :WIN32, but still get the same undefined function. Do you see anything else I can try?

Comment: you should reinstall de library with this flag out, and try again, but it seems that this shouldn't work